# Why a coverage filtered index do a Lookup

Tags: sql-server, lookup, filtered-index

I have a table that need to check every minute to alert when the total is greater than a number.

```
 SELECT 
  count(CreatedAt) Total
 FROM 
  Process d 
 WHERE 
  d.ProcessedAt is null
  AND DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), d.CreatedAt) > 30
```

My idea was create a filtered index, something like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FIX_Process_CreatedAt_ProcessedAt] ON [dbo].[Process]
(
    [CreatedAt] ASC
)
WHERE ProcessedAt IS NULL
```

But looking at the execution plan, there is a key lookup.

I don't understand why, becuase the index has the two columns for the query.

Can anyone explain me  why?

Comment: Your feeling is correct. This does not make sense and shouldn't be required logically. But it is an optimiser limitation that has never been fixed. You can vote for it here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/454744/filtered-index-not-used-and-key-lookup-with-no-output

Comment: @MartinSmith But here the situation is because ProcessedAt is different column than the CreatedAt column which is indexed, to accomplish that condition 'd.ProccessedAt is null' it has to use that value. For that optimizer has to do key lookup for getting the appropriate value. Bug which you mentioned is only if Indexed column and predicate columns are same.. I am yet to check the behaviour though..

Comment: No you've missed the point. It logically doesn't *have* to do key lookups to get that column at all. The condition it is checking is already guaranteed by the filtered index condition. The condition is true for all rows in the index. It logically can simply skip checking it as the OP suspected. The only reason the lookup is there is because the optimiser doesn't currently contain that logic but it could and should be added.

Comment: Yep you are correct in this example, I will add another example with my answer which does key lookup if there is a change in the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the condition is NULL then you will have only one value for the record set and why you require an index to that value? On what basis it will do sorting? So you need to do filtered index where processedAt is not null and use that condition in code will help

You need to include ProcessedAt column in INCLUDED Column in the create Index script

Adding an example for explaining @Martin Smith's comment:

Table script :

```
Create Table TestKeyLookup
(
id int identity(1,1) primary key -- Created PK which will create clustered Index
,id_for_filteredIndex int NOT NULL
,another_id int NOT NULL
)
```

Insert into table records :

```
declare @i int = 50
while @i < 1000000 
begin
    insert into TestKeyLookup (id_for_filteredIndex, another_id) values (@i, @i+5)
    set @i = @i + 10
END
```

Create Non Clustered filtered index on id_for_FilteredIndex column with condition on different column another_id

```
create nonclustered index NCI_TestKeyLookup on dbo.TestKeyLookup(id_for_filteredIndex)
where another_id > **673105**
```

If i query the table with exactly same condition then optimizer is not using KeyLookup

```
select  count(id_for_filteredIndex) from TestKeyLookup with(index(NCI_TestKeyLookup))
where another_id > 673105
```

[image: It does use filtered index]

If i change the condition by increasing even +5 or 10 then it does keyLookup to clustered index

```
select  count(id_for_filteredIndex) from TestKeyLookup with(index(NCI_TestKeyLookup))
where another_id > 673110
```

[image: Different Id where another_id is greater than filtered index condition]

I am trying to explain this only.. If there is a change in the condition then it uses KeyLookup to fetch. In a way you are correct if the column is nullable and it has null values then it is different

Comment: In the Process table it could have a lot of rows with ProcessedAt = NULL, each one with a different CreatedAt. The purpose of this index is to be used only in this query and be fast, since only need  to check for those with ProcessedAt is null, I've supposed that a filtered index could be a good solution.

Comment: Got you, now only checking that your indexing column is 'CreatedAt'..  Key lookup is because for the selected createdAt value it has to check the ProcessedAt column whether it is null or not, So it does key lookup, If you include ProcessedAt in 'Include column' you will get in index scan itself

Comment: I thought that adding the filter, the engine would realize and not need the column. Thanks!!!